# Arrays and Classes?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, member, subobject

I am new to C++ and working on a project where I have array of instances of a class, and within that class I have a struct that within that I have a function. 
How do I use that function within my main code block. I tried

```
class artwork {
    struct art {
        // the struct art contains important information such as artist, title and medium. 
    private:
        string artist;
    public:
        void setArtist(string values);
        string getArtist();
    };

    void artwork::art::setArtist(string values) {
        artist = values;
    }

int main (){
    artwork myartwork[500];
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {

        ///-----------------------------------
        ///-----------------------------------
        // below is where the error occurs? How do I reference setArtist?
        ///-----------------------------------
        ///-----------------------------------

        cout << myartwork[0].art.setArtist("Tim");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should start by posting valid code. That will make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things need to change here:

1. `class artwork` needs a member variable of type `art`
2. That member variable needs to be made public
3. The member variable needs to have a name different than the `art`, because that already names the type of the struct
4. You need a closing curly brace and semicolon for `artwork`

Your code should probably resolve to something like this:

```
class artwork {
public:
    struct art {
    private:
        string artist;
    public:
        void setArtist(string values){artist = values;}
        string getArtist(){return artist;}
    } art_;
};

int main (){
    artwork myartwork[500];
     for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
         myartwork[i].art_.setArtist("Tim");
         cout << myartwork[i].art_.getArtist();

     }
}
```

Other helpful tips:

1. Pass objects by reference
2. Initialize in constructors rather than with initialization methods
3. Prefer to do assignment initialization to a constructor for data agregation types
4. Loop against array size *not* magic numbers
5. Make getters return by const reference
6. Make methods that cannot change the state of the object const
7. Make members that do not change for the lifetime of the object const

**EDIT:**

Think of your class definition as the blueprint and the member as the actual object. If we wanted an `artwork` that had multiple `art` objects, in the case of a collaboration perhaps, then we could do this:

```
class artwork {
public:
    struct art {
    private:
        string artist;
    public:
        void setArtist(string values){artist = values;}
        string getArtist(){return artist;}
    };

    art art1_;
    art art2_;
};
```

Note that we don't define the `struct` twice, we just define 2 objects. Then if we had an artwork object like: `artwork foo` we could do:

```
foo.art1_("Sam Arnold"s);
foo.art2_("Jonathan Mee"s);
```

Comment: I made the member and it worked perfectly. Thank you. I am new to C++. and just picked up a book today to practice. I am not sure why I needed to make it a member vs a class though?

Comment: I've made an edit to try to help clarify the difference between a class definition and an object. We should probably open a new question if you have any other follow up issues, but try to look over that list of "helpful tips" there's a lot of key concepts in there.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell based on what's provided in the question, but you should be aware that C++ makes all class members "private" unless otherwise specified. In this case:

```
cout << myartwork[0].art.setArtist("Tim");
```

would fail for two reasons:

1. setArtist is not publicly accessible (because the art object is private, it doesn't matter that SetArtist is public, you can't get to it from outside)
2. cout is most likely expecting
   something to output, so setArtist (returning void) would likely
   present an issue